# How to populate calculated fields in nestjs resolver?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, nestjs

I recently switched from type-graphql to nestjs, to utilize features from nestjs.

I used to be able to set fields in the resolver, based on query args and db results, like distance and average rating etc.

```
@Resolver(Provider)
export class ProviderResolver {
  @Query((returns) => [Provider])
  async providers(@Args() { location, distance }: ProviderFilterArgs): Promise<Provider[]> {
    let providers: Provider[] = await ProviderModel.find();

    providers.map((provider) => {
      provider.distanceToProvider = getDistance(
        location ? location : [fooNumber, barNumber], // default coords
        provider.locations[0].geocode
      );

      return provider;
    });

    return providers;
  }
}
```

This approach doesn't seem to work in nestjs as the schema conflicts with the entity types (entity has "distanceToProvider" field, which the mongoose schema does not). Am I doing it wrong, or is it a bad practice to return a mapped db result?

Maybe it's possible to calculate and add the fields in a @ResolveField, but from what I understand, those are more for populating referenced Id's with another db call. Is it possible to do it, in a mongodb aggregation function?

How exactly am I supposed to add fields before returning the response?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are on the right track and I also think that your approach should be working in theory. Considering the fact that it does not work leads me to conclude that there is a problem with your shema definition. Can you post this please (the one this serive and the one for the DB)? Are they federated via a gateway? Does the DB-shema implement the Apollo-federation specification (i.e. is there a @key-directive?)?

If so then your service could most likely extend the type.
In this case @ResolveField would be the way to go and would be considered a good practice for sure.